# yum is trying to install a package PLUS dependency - I DO NOT want that dependency

Tags: package-management, yum, dependencies

I am trying to install grive in my CentOS server. The rpm available is:

```
grive-0.3.0-1.el6.xz.x86_64.rpm
```

The problem is that the rpm seems to be tied to json-c version 0.11 but the one I really need is json-c 0.10.

In short: when yum displays the message:

"Dependencies resolved - The following two packages will be installed:
grive and json-c 0.11"

is there any way to reply:

"Go ahead and install grive but **DO NOT** install (i.e. upgrade) json-c 0.11"

TIA

[image]

Comment: You realize that it is marked as a dependency because it won't *work* without it?

Comment: Gilles: In an ideal world, your comment would be correct. Many versions can fulfill the dependency. I have tried with json-c 0.11 and it does not work. Now I am going to try with json-c 0.10, because I happen to know that it is the same version used by a working application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yum doesn't have a way to do this.  It would counter the purpose of the package manager.  Moreover, it will usually render a package dysfunctional.  Package maintainer's put effort into ensuring dependencies are properly defined and not overly restrictive.

That said, you can install the rpm with the `rpm` utility using the `--nodeps` flag.   As a result, it becomes your responsibility to manually manage the package's life cycle.  Although this is generally unwise, you may find it useful to experiment with this option.  The syntax is:

```
rpm -i --nodeps [package].rpm
```

Yum statement on the matter: http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/NoDeps.html.

Comment: "Package maintainer's put effort into ensuring dependencies are properly defined and not overly restrictive." Sure, in an ideal world, where there are no bugs!

Answer (score 1):

Like shibley said, this would defeat the purpose of the package manager. It would be wiser to download the source and compile it with the version of the dependency you need. Hopefully, for you, the version you want will work without any source mods.

Comment: "...download the source and compile it..." - That would defeat the purpose of a package manager.

Comment: actually rpm is a package manager, yum is more of a repo manager/fetcher which can easily be replaced with `curl/wget` and `rpm`. So `yum` simply provides silly excuses for itself not having such a basic functionality.